# How to add new App to docky?

Tags: docky

There are some software's icons to add by default but i can't add alot more, I cant even add chorm on docky. There is not any customization setting for that so, How would I add program's shortcuts to docky.

Answer (score 1):

If your applications (Which can't add) installed using snap, you can use the following steps to solve the problem.

1. Copy the `.desktop` file into /usr/local/share/applications/ from /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/.
   or make a link by using `ln -s` command.

   For example:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/postman_postman.desktop /usr/local/share/applications/postman.desktop
   ```
2. Add the application by `Pin to Dock` option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't know the basic procedure for adding apps to the dock. 
When you open any application the app's icon should appear on the dock. When you first launch Docky it should show the apps you currently have opened on the dock.

To sticky an app to the dock right click on the icon of the app and select `pin to dock`.